# Populate a batch from a file

Tags: variables, batch-file, set, batch-processing, ping

I have been trying to work this 1 out it's a fairly simple batch but I'm pretty much lost, the searches got my close but none seemed to work so I'm hoping somebody can help with this.

I have a batch file, it is far from optimized but basically what I am trying to do now is use the ping I have running in the batch which is written to check.csv should then populate the individual IP's at the beginning (hope that makes sense).

in a nut shell
The variables at the beginning should be populated from check.csv

Here is the code

```
'@echo off
rem set the individual IP addresses

Rem these are manually set at present, I want these set automatically from check.csv which is created at the end of this file at present but will be moved infront..
set sarah=10.1.14.106
set richard=10.1.15.135
set kathh=10.1.12.79
```

edited out a number of these to reduce the code on screen for you, but they are all the same format, name & IP

```
rem set the individual profile name
set n1=sharman
set n2=rburrell
```

removed more of the same (just duplicates the above code for a different user)

```
rem set the computer name
set sarahPC=PB7B237     
set richardPC=PB1VAL9
```

removed more of the same

```
REM set the main install paths
set M3="C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Installers\M3.exe"
set H3="C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Installers\H3.exe"
set MooresInst="C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Catalogues\PD PS\Catalogue"
Rem menu
@echo off
cls
:start
echo.
echo 1   Ping
echo 2   List       
echo 3   DBase Installers   
echo 4   EXE Installers 
echo 5   End        
echo.
@CHOICE /C:12345

if errorlevel 5 goto End
if errorlevel 4 goto EXEInstallers
if errorlevel 3 goto DBase
if errorlevel 2 goto List   
if errorlevel 1 goto Ping   
goto End

:End
Pause
Exit


:EXEInstallers
echo EXE Installers
echo.
echo Upload folder
Xcopy %M3% "S:\# All Public\Information Technology\CAD\VWorlds" /s /y /q
Xcopy %H3% "S:\# All Public\Information Technology\CAD\VWorlds" /s /y /q
echo.
echo %sarah%
Xcopy %M3% "\\%sarah%\c$\Users\%n1%\Desktop\" /s /y /q
Xcopy %H3% "\\%sarah%\c$\Users\%n1%\Desktop\" /s /y /q
echo.
echo %richard%
Xcopy %M3% "\\%richard%\c$\Users\%n2%\Desktop\" /s /y /q
Xcopy %H3% "\\%richard%\c$\Users\%n2%\Desktop\" /s /y /q
echo.
```

removed more of the same (just duplicates the above code for a different user)

```
 goto Start

:DBase
echo Database Installers
echo.
echo %sarah%
Xcopy %MooresInst% "\\%sarah%\c$\Virtual Worlds\Catalogue" /s /y /q
echo.
echo %richard%
Xcopy %MooresInst% "\\%richard%\c$\Virtual Worlds\Catalogue" /s /y /q
echo.
```

removed more of the same (just duplicates the above code for a different user)

```
echo 
Goto Start

:List
 echo.
 echo This is a list of the IP's used currently, check against any that fail.
 echo.
echo Name       Puter       IP
echo sarah      %sarahPC%%sarah%
echo richard        %richardPC% %richard%
echo kathh      %kathhPC%       %kathh%
echo amarie     %amariePC%      %amarie%
```

removed more of the same (just duplicates the above code for a different user)

```
echo.
Pause
Goto Start

:Ping
@echo off
if exist "C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Copy to Desktop\Results.csv" Del  /s /q "C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Copy to Desktop\Results.csv"
Echo Pinging list...

set ComputerList=list.txt
pause
Echo Computername,IP Address>Final.csv
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%ComputerList%") do (
 for /f "tokens=3" %%B in ('ping -n 1 -l 1 %%A ^|findstr Reply ^|^| echo Not found Failed:')  do (
 set IPadd=%%B
 echo %%A,!IPadd:~0, -1!>>Check.csv
))

 pause
 Goto Start'
```

here is the check.csv file contents

```
PB1VAL9 10.1.15.135 
PB7B218 Failed 
PB1VAL8 10.1.15.111 
PB7B210 10.1.5.253
```

removed more of the same (just duplicates the above code for a different user)

Comment: Would help if you could make a smaller test example which demonstrated the problem, not all of that batch code is required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: done, hopefully what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this routine out to set your variables to ip addresses:

```
echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a in ("check.csv") (
    echo setting %%a=%%b
    set "%%a=%%b"
)
```

With this ping routine it shows if it is online or offline.  I had to guess what you were trying to do as we don't have your files to test it.

Give us a sample of `Check.csv` if you want to populate a set of variables with the IP addresses inside it.

```
:Ping
@echo off
Del  /s /q "C:\Users\dclare\Documents\VW Compiler\Copy to Desktop\Results.csv" 2>nul
Echo Pinging list...

set "ComputerList=list.txt"
pause
Echo Computername,IP Address>Final.csv

 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%ComputerList%") do (
    ping -n 1 -l 1 %%A >nul
       if not errorlevel 1 (
             >>Check.csv echo %%A,online
          ) else (
             >>Check.csv echo %%A,offline
        )
 )

 pause
 Goto Start
```

Comment: Hi the check.cvs is simply the IP's from this file I would like to get into the variables in the main code above, whereas at present I code them in by hand  
PB1VAL9 10.1.15.135
PB7B218 Failed
PB1VAL8 10.1.15.111
PB7B210 10.1.5.253
PB1VAE0 10.1.14.110
PB7B247 10.1.4.218
PBCPAB3 10.1.3.201
PBBFXH5 10.1.3.124
PB7B230 10.1.4.128
PB1VAM3 10.1.4.211
PB7B219 10.1.5.240
PBBFXD6 10.1.14.59

Comment: Can you edit your question and add it to your question, so it is in the right format?

Comment: Hi foxidrive, thats partially got it, it tells me if they are online, but it needs to take the IP addresses from the check.csv aswell and populate the IP addresses in the main body (hope that makes sense) where the 1st line reads set sarah=  this I need automatically populating from the check.csv. Sorry I don't think I have been clear enough on this

Comment: The smaller code block in my answer sets the variables - there is no `sarah/richard/kathh` in your sample file.